# Docker image looks different - jenkins/jenkins in mac systems

Tags: docker, docker-machine

When I run the following docker image in my **mac(intel)**

```
jenkins/jenkins
```

I get the following file structure:

```
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:13 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:13 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Jun 23 11:13 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:11 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr  2 11:55 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Jun 23 11:13 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:13 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr  2 11:55 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 lib64
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:11 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 224 root root    0 Jun 23 11:13 proc
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 05:50 root
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:13 run
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:10 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Jun 23 11:13 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:13 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:11 var
```

When i run the same image in **mac(M1)**, I get some changes in file structure.
The noticeable one that cause me an error is that i dont find lib64 directory here in this container.

The following the directory structure:

```
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:21 .
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:21 ..
-rwxr-xr-x   1 root root    0 Jun 23 11:21 .dockerenv
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:15 bin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr  2 11:55 boot
drwxr-xr-x   5 root root  340 Jun 23 11:21 dev
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:21 etc
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Apr  2 11:55 home
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 lib
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 media
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 mnt
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:15 opt
dr-xr-xr-x 208 root root    0 Jun 23 11:21 proc
drwx------   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:15 root
drwxr-xr-x   3 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 run
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:12 sbin
drwxr-xr-x   2 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 srv
dr-xr-xr-x  13 root root    0 Jun 23 11:21 sys
drwxrwxrwt   1 root root 4096 Jun 23 11:21 tmp
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 12 00:00 usr
drwxr-xr-x   1 root root 4096 Jun 20 14:15 var
```

I dont see lib64 dir here. Just the lib directory.

Any idea about this difference? Docker containers should be same, be it hosted in any architecture?, if they are the same images? Correct me!

Thanks!

Comment: Different architecture. The `x64`-libs are useless on an `arm`-based sysem. Hence, the `arm`-flavoured image does not include them.

Comment: @Turing85 but when i pull docker image with name jenkins/jenkins, i dont specify the architecture. I am running docker in 2 separte mac machines. Anyways docker images are supposed to be same whether we run in mac(intel) host or mac(m1) host. The docker daemon is the abstraction. If there are differences the whole point of images and containers become loomy!

Comment: "*Anyways docker images are supposed to be same whether we run in mac(intel) host or mac(m1) host.*" - That is where you are mistaken. Docker - by default - checks the architecture of the machine and pulls an image of that architecture (if we pull by tag that is). The intel mac has an `x64` architecture, the m1 mac has an `arm` architecture. Check the digest of the image on both machines; they will be different.

Comment: Yes the digest is different and i understood now! Thanks atone!!

Answer (score 2):

No, Container image for different architectures will be different. in your case both Mac machines have different architecture intel x86 M1 Arm

if you want to pull specific architecture image you can provide `--platform` flag

```
docker pull --platform linux/arm64 alpine:latest
```

Answer (score 2):

If you are using Mac M1, then the library should be of the below architecture specification:

```
Linux/AArch64
```

In case you are using Mac Intel:

```
Linux/x64
```

Here Linux means that the `jenkins/jenkins` image is built on a Linux image, while AArch64 or x64 is the host architecture. For Intel, it is x64, while for M1, it is AArch64 (ARM based).

Answer (score 1):

Docker images are indeed built for different architectures. See, for example, for the image you provided under the column "OS/ARCH": https://hub.docker.com/r/jenkins/jenkins/tags

See also the docker [documentation for multi-platform images](https://docs.docker.com/build/building/multi-platform/):

> Docker images can support multiple platforms, which means that a single image may contain variants for different architectures, and sometimes for different operating systems, such as Windows.
>
> When running an image with multi-platform support, docker automatically selects the image that matches your OS and architecture.