# Cannot run Docker Image on Mac M1: Error io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)

Tags: docker, macos, nginx

I have my docker images on docker hub and pulled them to my Mac M1 and tried to run those images but always get the error `io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)`.

The images work fine on my Windows PC but I'm not sure what the problem is with the Mac? This is kinda ridiculous because I thought the purpose of docker is that you can run your application no matter on what machine but it seems not to be the case.

I have two images (Backend with Express.js which runs fine but the Frontend with Angular, I get that error that some Function is not implemented)

```
2023-06-30 16:31:55 /docker-entrypoint.sh: /docker-entrypoint.d/ is not empty, will attempt to perform configuration
2023-06-30 16:31:55 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Looking for shell scripts in /docker-entrypoint.d/
2023-06-30 16:31:56 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh
2023-06-30 16:31:56 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: Getting the checksum of /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf
2023-06-30 16:31:56 10-listen-on-ipv6-by-default.sh: info: /etc/nginx/conf.d/default.conf differs from the packaged version
2023-06-30 16:31:56 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/20-envsubst-on-templates.sh
2023-06-30 16:31:56 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Launching /docker-entrypoint.d/30-tune-worker-processes.sh
2023-06-30 16:31:56 /docker-entrypoint.sh: Configuration complete; ready for start up
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: using the "epoll" event method
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: nginx/1.23.3
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: built by gcc 10.2.1 20210110 (Debian 10.2.1-6) 
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: OS: Linux 5.15.49-linuxkit-pr
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: getrlimit(RLIMIT_NOFILE): 1048576:1048576
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: start worker processes
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 67
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 69
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 71
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [notice] 1#1: start worker process 72
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [emerg] 67#67: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [emerg] 69#69: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [emerg] 72#72: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
2023-06-30 16:31:56 2023/06/30 07:31:56 [emerg] 71#71: io_setup() failed (38: Function not implemented)
```

Already have uninstalled and reinstalled Docker, but getting the same error again.

Comment: Docker images can indeed be built for different architectures. I assume that your image is only available for a specific architecture (x64 most likely)? You would need to build it for `arm` as well to make it work on the M1. Also [see this recent question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76539843/docker-image-looks-different-jenkins-jenkins-in-mac-systems). If you share the Dockerfile where we could see the base images this could be confirmed.